# Missing required argument $encoder of MSP\TwoFactorAuth\Model\UserConfigManager

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.2

I am facing this issue on Magento 2.3.2 Enterprise Edition

ON Deployment Getting Following error.

```
In AbstractFactory.php line 238:

  Missing required argument $encoder of MSP\TwoFactorAuth\Model\UserConfigMan  
  ager.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On June 25, 2019, the Magento version 2.3.2 was released. Improvements to Magento 2.3.2 require installing libsodium cryptographic library version 1.0.13 or higher. Without this you will get an error in the MSP_TwoFactorAuth module.

Try below command for Linux (Fedora)

```
dnf install libsodium
```

Also execute command for magento

> rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/*
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Thanks its Working

Comment: Same here, had to run `yum install libsolidium` and run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` two times